# Probability that every polygon contains almost exactly the expected number of samples

Tags: probability, geometry, conditional-probability, recreational-mathematics

Let's uniformly sample $n$ times from the unit square. Define a polygon contained within the unit square with area $A$. Surely as $n \to \infty$, the probability that the polygon contains at least $\lfloor{nA}\rfloor$ samples and at most $\lceil{nA}\rceil$ samples tends to 1. What I'm interested in is if there are $m$ polygons, $m = kn$, where the polygons may overlap arbitrarily, does the probability that every polygon has at least $\lfloor{nA_i}\rfloor$ and at most $\lceil{nA_i}\rceil$ samples tend to 1 as well?

Comment: Assuming $n\ge 0$ and $A \ge 0$, you will have $\lfloor{nA}\rfloor\ge 0$ so you do not need $\max(0,...)$

Comment: It is more usual to write  $m |n$ rather than $n|m$ to indicate $n$ is a multiple of $m$.

Comment: Actually I meant $m$ is a multiple of $n$

Comment: Oh yeah thanks. I removed the $max(0, ...)$

Comment: If $m$ is a multiple of $n$, what is increasing? Is $n$ fixed and $m$ increasing?  Or $m=kn$ so they are increasing together with a fixed multiple? Or something else?  Do the new polygons overlap or are they getting smaller?

Comment: $m = kn$. The polygons overlap arbitrarily. I'll update the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement

> Surely as $n \to \infty$, the probability that the polygon contains at least $\max(0, \lfloor{nA}\rfloor)$ samples and at most $\lceil{nA}\rceil$ samples tends to $1$

is incorrect.  It would be correct to say that the number contained in the polygon divided by $n$ converges towards $A$ in a law-of-large-numbers sense, but that is not saying the same thing.  Flip a fair coin $1$ million times, and the proportion of heads will probably be close to $\frac12$ but the probability you see exactly $500\,000$ heads is about $0.0008$.

The number sampled in the polygon has a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $A$, so expectation $nA$ and variance $nA(1-A)$ which is increasing with $n$. The probability that the numbered sampled in the polygon is somewhere from  $\lfloor{nA}\rfloor$ through to $\lceil{nA}\rceil$ converges to $0$ as $n$ increases.

With $m$ polygons, the probability is of course lower that they are all in this interval than that one specific one is.

Comment: Ah yes. I have a follow up question which I'll ask as part of a separate Question. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Henry, my follow up question is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4819343/the-smallest-d-which-almost-ensures-every-polygon-will-contain-expected-number-o

Comment: Your next question (with a wider band, but still of fixed size) is going to face the same issue as this one: for any $A$ with positive area and any $d>0$, the probability the  number sampled in $A$ being in $[nA-d,nA+d]$ will converge to $0$ in the same sense.  You need something like $[n(A-d),n(A+d)]$ for convergence to $1$

Comment: Hi Henry, actually $d$ was expressed as a function of $n$ and $A$. Would you be so kind as to take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4820616/probability-that-at-least-one-of-many-random-polygons-contains-twice-the-expecte please? This is the last question in this chain of questions I have, with it being the least abstract